# SwiftUI strange layout behaviour inside contextMenu

Tags: swiftui, layout

I have some contextMenu which shows some kind of modal view.

```
.contextMenu {
    if let shownItem {
      ModalSheet(taskModel: shownItem)
    }
}
```

and the modal sheet itself is just container for LabeledContent

```
{
        VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
            
            Text(taskModel.title + taskModel.title + taskModel.title + taskModel.title + taskModel.title)
                .lineLimit(3)
                .font(.system(size: 11, weight: .regular))
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            
            LabelContent(label: "Release") {
                TextEditor(text: $release)
                    .frame(width: 205, height: 24)
                    .cornerRadius(6)
                    .colorMultiply(.gray)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .cornerBorder(6, color: .gray.opacity(0.15))
            }
            Spacer()
            LabelContent(label: "Author") {
                TextEditor(text: $release)
                    .frame(width: 205, height: 24)
                    .cornerRadius(6)
                    .colorMultiply(.gray)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .cornerBorder(6, color: .gray.opacity(0.15))
            }
            Spacer()
            LabelContent(label: "Priority") {
                Menu {
                    ForEach(PriorityModel.allCases, id: \.self) { priority in
                        Button("\(priority.rawValue)") {
                            self.priority = priority
                        }
                        Divider.appStyled()
                    }
                } label: {
                    Text(priority.rawValue)
                        .cornerRadius(6)
                        .colorMultiply(.gray)
                        .lineLimit(1)
                        .cornerBorder(6, color: .gray.opacity(0.15))
                }
                .frame(width: 205, height: 24)
            }
            
            Spacer()
            LabelContent(label: "Description") {
                TextEditor(text: $release)
                    .frame(width: 205)
                    .cornerRadius(6)
                    .colorMultiply(.gray)
                    .cornerBorder(6, color: .gray.opacity(0.15))
            }
        }
        .foregroundColor(Color(nsColor: .fromHEX(0xD0CFD1)))
        .padding(14)
        .background(Color(nsColor: .fromHEX(0x211D26)))
        .border(Color(nsColor: .fromHEX(0x37333B)), width: 1)
        **.frame(width: 305, height: 293)**
        .onAppear {
            release = taskModel.release
            author = taskModel.author
            priority = taskModel.priority
            description = taskModel.taskDescription
        }
    }
```

As we can see i'm specifying fixed size for the whole modal sheet.
So I expect it to be exactly 305x293 in size.

But in reality it looks like this:

[image]

It looks like something contextMenu tells all its siblings to have fixedSize

But I don't know is it even possible

And this how it should look like:

[image]

Comment: Would a `.popover` not be more appropriate for the type of view you're trying to create here? A context menu, as its name suggests, is really designed to accommodate a list of buttons or similar controls, whereas you're looking to show a form-style view.

Comment: @ScottM yes exactly, but I'm just curious what is the logic behind such a outlandish layout?